# Matlab bsxfun(@times,...,...) equivalent in R

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, element

Has **R** got an equivalent of *Matlab* `bsxfun(@times,a,b)`? Suppose one would like to perform an `element wise multiplication` on matrix `a,b`:

**Matlab:**

```
a=[1 0 3 -4];
b=[0 1 5 7; 2 9 -3 4];

bsxfun(@times,a,b) = [0 0 15 -28; 2 0 -9 -16]
```

**R:**

```
a<-c(1,0,3,-4)
b<-matrix(c(0,2,1,9,5,-3,7,4),nrow = 2,ncol = 4)

a * b = matrix(c(0,0,3,-36,5,0,21,-16),nrow = 2,ncol = 4)
```

Any idea on the way **R** gets the results of above of `a*b`, as I was expecting it to be identical to *Matlab* `bsxfun(@times,a,b)`

**EDIT:**

```
bsxfun("*",repmat(a,2,1),b) # using R {pracma}
```

Best

Comment: Just to clarify: the actual (base-R way) answer to the question is actually in the _comments_ of the accepted answer below: use the `sweep` function.

Comment: (It got added to the answer body in 2016.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with column major matrices, since that is the R-convention:

```
> b<-matrix(c(0,2,1,9,5,-3,7,4),nrow = 4,ncol = 2)
> a*b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    5
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    3   21
[4,]  -36  -16
```

If you take your original construction of `b` you get a bit of an unpleasant surprise when you try to use `sweep`:

```
> b2<-matrix(c(0,2,1,9,5,-3,7,4),nrow = 2,ncol = 4)
> sweep(b2, 2, a, '*')
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0   15  -28
[2,]    2    0   -9  -16
```

Since the `matrix` function uses column major filling of postions, and you didn't specify byrow=TRUE in its call, the `b`-matrix is different than your Matlab matrix.

```
> b3<-matrix(c(0,2,1,9,5,-3,7,4),nrow = 2,ncol = 4, byrow=TRUE)
> sweep(b3, 2, a, '*')
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    3  -36
[2,]    5    0   21  -16
```

Comment: Fair enough... Thanks as your suggestion matches my expectation. However, one might **leave a bit hungry for more** in regards to the statement :_"that's the R-convention"_. Best,

Comment: As an alternative to the R convention, I've **edited** the post with a solution I have been working on, fyi

Comment: If you wanted to do it with a base-R function the `sweep` operation can be used. I'll post an example. (Nothing against pkg:pracma. It is a rich source of useful functions. It's been around forever and is well tested.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional alternative with `sweep`. Best,

Comment: R and packages are open source. Obviously, nobody has come up with the idea to inform the maintainer of 'pracma' about better versions or even provided some code. Where did the good old customs go?

Comment: @HansW: Thanks for the back-handed compliment. I didn't really imagine that I would have come up with better programming strategies than the author of pkg:`pracma`. That has so many gems in it that I'm rather in awe of its author's overall brilliance. I particularly like `vectorfield`.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches given "bsxfun" and "sweep" are not optimal from the perspective of execution speed. The performance of "bsxfun" is actually so dismal that it seems useless for non-toy applications.

In my benchmark the fastest was the approach

`matrix(a, ncol = n_col,  nrow = nsample, byrow = TRUE) * b`

`sweep()` becomes more competitive when matrix size increases but takes double amount of time even for moderately large matrices (1e6-by-4).

Find full benchmark below

---

```
# test of recycling efficiency

rm(list=ls())

library(microbenchmark)
library(pracma)

a = c(1,0,3,-4)
n_col = 4

# make example more realistic by expanding number of rows of b
nsample = 1e3
b = repmat(matrix(c(0,2,1,9,5,-3,7,4),nrow = 2,ncol = n_col), nsample / 2, 1)

print(microbenchmark(
  erg_1 = matrix(a, ncol = n_col,  nrow = nsample, byrow = TRUE) * b,
  erg_2 = matrix(rep.int(a, nsample), nrow = nsample, ncol = n_col, byrow = TRUE) * b,
  erg_3 = matrix(a * c(t(b)), nrow = nsample, ncol = n_col, byrow = TRUE),
  erg_4 = sweep(b, 2, a, '*'),
  erg_5 = bsxfun('*', repmat(a, nsample, 1), b) 
  ))


#same as above but now larger matrices
nsample = 1e6
b = repmat(matrix(c(0,2,1,9,5,-3,7,4),nrow = 2,ncol = n_col), nsample / 2, 1)

print(microbenchmark(
  erg_1 = matrix(a, ncol = n_col,  nrow = nsample, byrow = TRUE) * b,
  erg_2 = matrix(rep.int(a, nsample), nrow = nsample, ncol = n_col, byrow = TRUE) * b,
  erg_3 = matrix(a + c(t(b)), nrow = nsample, ncol = n_col, byrow = TRUE),
  erg_4 = sweep(b, 2, a, '*')
  #erg_5 = bsxfun('*', repmat(a, nsample, 1), b) #bsxfun is non-competitive
))

>Unit: microseconds
  expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 erg_1    9.057   10.1135   11.93394   11.0195   12.6790   36.226   100
 erg_2   14.189   15.3970   18.75324   16.9060   19.9250   41.358   100
 erg_3   26.263   28.8295   35.04538   30.9430   34.8675   86.941   100
 erg_4   40.452   44.0750   56.88289   51.4705   66.4130  109.279   100
 erg_5 2694.827 2968.4755 3243.76025 3208.9185 3417.5125 5575.306   100
>Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 erg_1 10.85538 11.30668 20.58625 12.93408 13.28290 69.17918   100
 erg_2 16.07206 18.00058 29.17394 18.24751 20.09845 75.30993   100
 erg_3 22.41231 24.58957 30.83620 24.99544 26.49047 79.71910   100
 erg_4 20.74838 21.53673 29.52071 22.88867 23.30420 81.07150   100
```

Comment: R and packages are open source. Obviously, nobody has come up with the idea to inform the maintainer of 'pracma' about better versions or even provided some code. Where did the good old customs go?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: There were indeed bugs where sweep choked on shapes like (1,10,2). Hence I wrote another implementation based on how sweep was written. The speed is somehow compromised due to re-casting, but still 4x faster. The implementation is deposited on a github repo [bsxfun.R](https://github.com/shouldsee/Rutil/blob/master/R/bsxfun.R) (benchmarker taken from @g g)

I would like to abbreviate the MARGIN to be swept, but `pracma::bsxfun（）` was not using `sweep()`. So I wrote the following (see github link), hopefully without a bug.

tag: R, pracma, array

Comment: R and packages are open source. Obviously, nobody has come up with the idea to inform the maintainer of 'pracma' about better versions or even provided some code. Where did the good old customs go?

Comment: As a novice programmer, I use StackOverflow for most of my questions these days. Maybe we should encourage package maintainer to monitor this forum for possible improvements.